# Using File::Find::Rule to get the list of files in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to identify the list of all .cpp files in my repository. I am using the following script:

```
use File::Find::Rule;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->name('*.cpp');
print Dumper @files;
```

I get the following output:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'mindepth' => undef,
             'maxdepth' => undef,
             'extras' => {},
             'subs' => {},
             'iterator' => [],
             'rules' => [
                          {
                            'args' => [
                                        '*.cpp'
                                      ],
                            'rule' => 'name',
                            'code' => 'm{(?-xism:^(?=[^\\.])[^/]*\\.cpp$)}'
                          }
                        ]
           }, 'File::Find::Rule' );
```

I could not find any references online about fetching the list of files.

Can someone please point me to how to get the required list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.cpp')->in('.');
```